# Passing event to another class

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I have a class that inherits from a base class. This base class exposes an event that can be handled within the child class. I'm trying to create a library which is as de-coupled as possible and was wondering how I can program it so that I can instantiate my library object within the child class but route the inherited event into the the library object.

Specifically, I'm creating a Windows Phone 7 project in Silverlight. I have a standard XAML page and am handling the `Touch.FrameReported` event. What I'd like to do is have my external library object handle the `Touch.FrameReported` event on behalf of any page that instantiates it. This way, any new page I create that instantiates my library object can have that library object handle the event rather than copying the handling code in every XAML page.

I hope my post isn't confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using something like the EventAggregator found in PRISM v4 or the Messenger in [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). Both would provide an event messaging infrastructure allowing you to decouple your views.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At the moment, I don't understand MVVM to a good enough degree to convert my current project to that pattern and with the deadline coming up, it's be best for me to stick with my current method.

Comment: You don't have to use the whole library or make your app MVVM. You could just use the Messenger functionality.